# Blinking Led in Bare-Metal C programming: STM32L476RG Nucleo Board

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller, stm32, cortex-m

I tried to implement a classic blink example on an STM32L476RG Nucleo board.

According to the STM32L4x datasheet: the LD2 is connected to the GPIOA PORT 5 (PA5).
The PA5 uses the AHB2 bus.

**Note:** I used Keil uVision 5; I created a New uVision Project with STM32L476RGTx target.
In the "Manage Run-Time Environment" dialog box I selected:

1. CMSIS >> Core (flag)
2. Device >> Startup  (flag)

Here the code:

```
#include "stm32l4xx.h"                  // Device header
//#include <stdint.h>

//#define MASK(x) ((uint32_t) (1<<(x))) // bitmasking 

void delayMs(int delay);

int main(void){
    // RCC->AHB2RSTR |=1; 
    // RCC->AHB2RSTR &=~1; 
    // RCC->AHB2ENR |= MASK(0); //bitwise OR. Enable GPIOA clock
     RCC->AHB2ENR |= 1;
     //GPIOA->MODER |= MASK(10);
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x400; 

    while(1){


        //GPIOA->ODR |= MASK(4);
         GPIOA->ODR |= 0x20;
        delayMs(500);
        //GPIOA->ODR &= ~MASK(4);
        GPIOA->ODR &= ~0x20;
        delayMs(500);
    }
}

void delayMs(int delay){
int i;
    for(;delay>0; delay --){
        for (i=0; i<3195;i++);
    }
}
```

The Build output returns:

```
Build started: Project: blinknew
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 6 (build 750)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
Build target 'Target 1'
compiling main.c...
linking...
Program Size: Code=520 RO-data=408 RW-data=0 ZI-data=1632  
".\Objects\blinknew.axf" - 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:09
```

and when I download it, Keil uV 5 returns:

```
 Load "C:\\Users\\gmezz\\OneDrive\\Documenti\\Bare_Metal\\Blinknew\\Objects\\blinknew.axf" 
Erase Done.
Programming Done.
Verify OK.
Flash Load finished at 22:37:52
```

The LED should blink with a period of 1 s, but in reality, nothing happens.

Honestly, I don't understand what is going wrong.

Someone can help me?

GM

Comment: And what is happening with this program? What is the problem you have? Do you get build errors? Unexpected results when running? Crashes when running? Please read or refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The question has been edited. GM

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to read the target's documentation and to learn how to set and reset port pins. BTW, there should be some example with your Keil IDE, at least this was true when I tried µVision some years ago. IIRC it is called "blinky" which does pretty much what you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but according to the reference manual (RM0351) section 6.2.19, you should wait 2 clock cycles after enabling the peripheral clock, before accessing its registers. Try introducing a short delay after RCC->AHB2ENR |= 1; line. In your case, I think MODER register is not getting the correct value.

I also suggest checking the actual values of registers with a debugger.

Comment: I solved reading the registers. The GPIOA_MODER has a reset value of 0xABFFFFFF, so I cannot use a bitwise operator as in the code. I need to put 0xABFFF7FF, to set the PA5 direction.

Comment: Ah, I missed that one. It seems L series are different from F series when it comes to reset values of MODER registers.